# Partitioning in oracle 12c

Tags: oracle

Can we perform partitioning on tables in Oracle 12c R1 on existing tables? I don't want to drop the existing tables. The new feature is available in R2 but can we do it in R1?

Comment: Please name the specific feature. I can't tell if you are thinking of "Moving Partitions online" or something else.

Comment: Why don't you check the manual. If that is available 12.1, then it should be in the same chapter of the manual as in 12.2

Comment: You can use package [DBMS_REDEFINITION](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_redefi.htm#CBBJJAIF), it exists for many releases (at least since 10gR2)